# What is the French idiomatic equivalent of "burning issues"?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques

In English, ***burning issues*** means matters of very urgent concern, most important. When I tried to find the French equivalent of that, [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=burning%20issue) gave me a few hits like

> - questions brûlantes (which seems too close to the original English to be idiomatic in French)
> - Problèmes / affaires urgent(e)s (which seems too explicative)

Is there an idiomatic set phrase for this?

Comment: "Dossiers brûlants" springs to mind but there is probably a better answer

Comment: Selon contexte *actualité brûlante* : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sujet+br%C3%BBlant%2Cquestion+br%C3%BBlante%2Cactualit%C3%A9+br%C3%BBlante&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2Csujet%20br%C3%BBlant%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsujet%20br%C3%BBlant%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSujet%20br%C3%BBlant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cquestion%20br%C3%BBlante%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bquestion%20br%C3%BBlante%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQuestion%20br%C3%BBlante%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cactualit%C3%A9%20br%C3%BBlante%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Brûlant` actually works very well in that case, it sounds idiomatic to me in `sujets brûlants`, `questions brûlantes`… Absolutely safe to use here.

> Il nous reste à traiter les deux questions brûlantes évoquées ce matin.

> Je préfère confier ce sujet particulièrement brûlant à quelqu'un d'expérimenté.

It might be your best bet over other translations, because `brûlant` keeps the double connotation of `very urgent` and `very delicate`. Some of that is lost in `affaires urgentes` given by Linguee.

- [Definition of 'brûlant' in the TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/br%C3%BBlant)
- [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sujet+br%C3%BBlant%2Cquestion+br%C3%BBlante%2Cprobl%C3%A8me+br%C3%BBlant%2Cdossier+br%C3%BBlant&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true)

Answer (score 1):

> Questions [cruciales](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/crucial).
>  Questions [pressantes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pressant).

Comment: Helps keep it cool.